# Angular; how to re-render component data when I update variable in script. Binding data is working, but not updating

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, render

I'm trying to update the text in the span, using the latest Angular. However, I do not understand clearly how lifecycle hooks and update work in Angular. Issue is with `fileName` - I bind the data and it gets the initial value when the page loads. However when the data variable updated, I can see changes in the console, but the component itself is not updated.

Shall I use some Lifecycle methods or something else?
I've read: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks and didn't make clear for me.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="putToBucket()" class='form-class' >
  <label for="image_uploads" >Select Image</label>
  <input type='file' id="image_uploads" (change) ='onFileSelected($event)' class='input-button' multiple>
  <span  > {{fileName }} </span>
  <button class='submit-button' type='submit' >Submit</button> 
</form>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})


export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
     private toastr: ToastrService) { }
  urlApi = '//myuri api';
  respond;
  fileName: Array<any> =['Test']


 onFileSelected(event) {
    //console.log(event.target.files[0].name)
    let name = event.target.files[0].name;
    this.fileName.push(name)
    console.log(this.fileName)
```

Example of what I see: 
[image]

Comment: Do you not see anything? Or does it say `[object Object]`? A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) with a minimal reproducible example may also help.

Comment: I see 'Test'. When I add picture I see array of 2 items in the console, but still Test on the render. I updated the post and attached the picture to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fileName is an array so to display it you have to iterate it in .html file or you can change fileName to string and do as shown below.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  fileName="Test";

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.fileName);
  }

  onFileSelected(newName){
    this.fileName=newName;
    console.log(this.fileName);
  }
}
```

.html file

```
<button (click)="onFileSelected('newFile')">change file name</button>
```

Working Demo : [demo](https://angular-bqzhxe.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Thank you, it works with changing the array to string. However if I upload multiple files and want to display all names - I should loop with *ngFor module?

Comment: Yes, then you should use *ngFor directive.

Comment: Thanks, already did. Thank you for help, I was thinking in a wrong direction :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
 fileName : Array<any> = [];


  onFileSelected(event){
console.log(event.target.files[0].name)
let name = event.target.files[0].name;
    this.fileName.push(name)
    console.log(this.fileName)
  }
```

```html
<input type='file' id="image_uploads" (change) ='onFileSelected($event)' class='input-button' multiple>
<span   *ngFor="let list of fileName">{{list}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to implement `onPush` or `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in your component

Doing this will instruct Angular to run change detection on these components and their sub-tree only when new references are passed to them versus when data is simply mutated.

Run `this.ref.markForCheck()` or `this.ref.detectChanges()` when you update your variable and want it to reflect in html

Please check the following links for more information

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

Comment: Thank you, I will check it. But isn't it too complicated for small re-render of text?